# Would there be any problems using private/public key encryption for saving a password?

Tags: passwords, public-key-encryption

Using hashing algorithms like md5 we suffer from a limited entropy which means that very long passwords might result in hashes that can be regenerated by a shorter password.

I was thus wondering if it would be a good idea to store a password **encrypted with the public key** of public/private key encryption on the server. As decrypting is not needed, one could just **throw away the secret key** to avoid losing passwords when the server is compromised.

However, this method does not seem to be used widely. So are there drawbacks? If yes, then which?

Comment: How would you verify it?

Comment: I would encrypt the input with the same public key one more time and check if the output would be the same. Same as you do with hashing-algorithms.

Comment: Are there encryption schemes that pad the input with random bytes?  If so, you'd have to be sure not to use them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is always the drawback that computing a cryptographic hash is much less costly than encrypting a tiny password with a public-key encryption algorithm.

Secondly, you still suffer from limited entropy with public-key encryption, your bit string will still be limited. If you need more bits, use a hash with a bigger internal state (SHA-512, Whirlpool, etc...)

Third, you would need to store the public key along with the password, which results in a pretty hefty storage cost (considering how big public keys are), and if you're thinking of using the same public key for all passwords, don't - if that key is compromised it's over.

Also another consideration: without a password size limit there's a chance even padded block encryption will result in different storage sizes for different passwords, which can make database indexing a hell of a lot more difficult (probably not a huge concern but to keep in mind).

And finally, the biggie - hashes are meant to unequivocally destroy all structure in the input data, which is exactly what you want when storing passwords for verification. Encryption algorithms don't do that - they transform the data to make it unintelligible **without the proper key**, which sort of goes against what you're trying to use it for.

So, no, this method should not be used because it is self-defeating. Use a hash with a bigger internal state.

Comment: Lower performance could actually be a *benefit*, for passwords; it'd slow down the password check enough to make brute force take centuries, while legit users would barely notice.

Comment: You could just iterate the hash if this is a concern though - iirc md5 had an official standard for iterated hashing.

Answer (score 3):

There are several drawbacks.  Among them:

- You now have a token which must be protected.  If someone gets your secret key, they have every password that was encrypted with that key.  Asymmetric encryption is less of an issue if you "lose" the private key, but you better pray all copies of it are gone.  Hashes can't be decrypted, period.
- An encrypted password can be pretty much any length, and thus would require a pretty large field in the database (or length limits for the plaintext) in order to be stored.  Hashes have a known length.
- If you can decrypt the password, you know it.  If ever there was a problem with someone using that password to break into something else, everyone who knew that password belonged to that user is a suspect.  That now means you.  Even if you use one-way encryption as a hash, you'd better be able to prove you can't decrypt it -- and then, if you don't want to decrypt it, why encrypt?

Generally, you'd only choose encryption over hashing when you have to know the password for something else -- like, say, when you're using it to log in to another system on behalf of the user.  And ideally, you'd exhaust all other possibilities first.